# Remove jacket from SER cable for the last 5 feet?

Tags: electrical, subpanel

I am running 2-2-2-4 AL SER cable from my main panel to a subpanel in my garage. Referring to the picture, I have my SER cable run in the basement from my main panel up to the other side of the wall shown, where I was going to put a junction box that is then connected to the LB and transition from the AL SER cable to #2 THHN/THWN-2 conductors. The thing is I cannot find anyone that carries #2 AWG THHN/THWN-2 AL wire by the foot, since I only need about 6 feet. Can I take the sheathing off the SER cable and feed the 4 conductors through the last 6 feet of conduit, even though to be by-the-book, the 4 separate conductors from the SER cable should be labeled?  It would also be nice to not have to purchase an 8 X 8 junction box.

[image]